# Are rails module instance variables available to other classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following a textbook and building a simple RoR application. One thing that's confusing me in one step is that it seems like a variable in a module is somehow being accessed by the controller that includes it without any accessor. Here's the module:

```
   module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private
    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end

end
```

and the controller calling it

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ....
  def create
    @product = Product.find(Params[:prouct_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)
 ...
end
```

Do you see it? @cart is being used like its variable it has access to. I'm pretty new to both Ruby and Rails but can someone explain how this is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including a module in a class extends the class to include the module's methods and instance vars (at least those that have been set). In this case @cart is available in the controller because a) the module has been included, and b) there is a before_action that calls the `set_cart` method (which sets @cart).

You can essentially think of the contents of the module as appearing directly in the controller, once you include it. That's not exactly true, because when the methods are extracted into the module you have the opportunity to override them in the class, but for the sake of your case it holds.

Edit for clarification: you don't need an accessor because the module's methods and ivars belong to the same instance of the controller class.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was something like that but couldn't find the documentation. I'll read up on it more.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you using incorrect terms. `@my_var = 1` sets instance (!) variable, while `my_var = 1` declares and sets local variable. Instance variables belong to object and always accessible inside of it. Local variables accessible only in a context they were declared.

Now about `include`. Long story short `include` adds your module to class hierarchy so you can think of it as "like  inheritance". So in your code `@cart` is not an instance variable of your module, its an instance variable of an object which class definition includes your module. 
If you need details please read the article. http://tech.pro/tutorial/1149/understanding-method-lookup-in-ruby-20

Finally rails helper `before_action` steps in and calls methods listed before action is executed.

Answer (score -1):

No. You'd have to provide methods for that in your module

```
module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def create_line_items(product)
     @cart.line_items.build(product: product)
  end

  private
    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end

end
```

And

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ....
  def create
    @product = Product.find(Params[:prouct_id])
    @line_item = create_line_items(@product)
 ...
end
```